# How can I get a Zeraora in Pokemon Ultra Moon?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I finished the Main and Post game in Pokemon Ultra Moon and I heard some talk about a pokemon called Zeraora.

Can you tell me how/where to find one?

Comment: This game has been out long enough for this information to be commonly available.  What research have you done on your own?

Answer (score 5):

As of when I'm writing (2018-04-25) it has only just been officially revealed (though it's existence was discovered by data miners) and is unobtainable using legitimate methods.

It will probably be distributed through an official event or in the next games.

As a side note, you do not require Zeraora for your regional Pokédex to be considered complete so there isn't much point in getting it early.